# Redirecting domain without changing URL

Tags: .htaccess

I have dynamic PHP file, but i need have URL like normal XML file.

My url: http://127.0.0.1/test/xml.xml?id=1&key=123

I add this line to htaccess file, but not working:

```
RewriteRule ^xml.xml(.*) xml.php$1 [P]
```

So how redirect one url to other without changing URL.

Comment: What is the URL you want to display and what is your actual URL?

Comment: I need always display the same url (http://127.0.0.1/test/xml.xml?id=1&key=123).

Comment: What URL do you want `http://127.0.0.1/test/xml.xml?id=1&key=123` should be forwarded to?

Comment: Should open: My url: http://127.0.0.1/test/xml.php?id=1&key=123

Answer (score 0):

Are you not missing a `$`

     `RewriteRule ^xml.xml(.*)$ http://your.proxyed.url.xml.php/$1 [P]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule in your site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(test/xml)\.xml$ $1.php [L,NC]
```

If you already have `/test/.htaccess` then use:

```
RewriteRule ^(xml)\.xml$ $1.php [L,NC]
```